# How can I fix these TypeScript Element implicitly has an 'any' type error in my reducer slice?

Tags: typescript, react-redux

I am in the process of converting a rather convoluted Redux reducer slice from JS to TS. I have fixed most of the errors from help I found here and from a course I am taking online. Still, two errors persist. Here is the code of the reducer slice with comments to indicate the errors I see in my IDE:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export type Column<T extends string> = {
  status: T
  title: 'To do' | 'In progress' | 'Done'
  taskIds: string[]
}

export type Columns = {
  [key in 'TO_DO' | 'IN_PROGRESS' | 'DONE']: Column<key>
}

export type Task = {
  id: string
  title: string
  description?: string
  status: 'TO_DO' | 'IN_PROGRESS' | 'DONE'
  board: string,
  user?: string
  created_at?: string
}

export type Tasks = {
  [key: string]: Task
}

interface TaskPayload {
  task: Task
}

interface EditTaskPayload {
  task: {
    boardId: string
    column: 'IN_PROGRESS' | 'TO_DO' | 'DONE'
    description?: string
    id: string
    status: 'IN_PROGRESS' | 'TO_DO' | 'DONE'
    title: string
  }
}

interface DeleteTaskPayload {
  column: 'TO_DO' | 'IN_PROGRESS' | 'DONE'
  id: string
}

interface MoveTaskPayload {
  taskId: string
  sourceIndex: number
  sourceColumn: 'TO_DO' | 'IN_PROGRESS' | 'DONE'
  destinationIndex: number
  destinationColumn: 'TO_DO' | 'IN_PROGRESS' | 'DONE'
}

interface HydrateTasksPayload {
  board: {
    id: string
    name: string
    description?: string
    TO_DO: string[]
    IN_PROGRESS: string[]
    DONE: string[]
  }
  tasks: {
    id: string
    title: string
    description?: string
    status: 'TO_DO' | 'IN_PROGRESS' | 'DONE'
    board: string
  }[]
}

export type TaskSlice = {
  boardId: string
  boardName: string
  boardDescription?: string
  tasks: Tasks
  columns: Columns
  columnOrder: ['TO_DO', 'IN_PROGRESS', 'DONE']
}

export const  reduceTasks = (tasks: Task[]) => {
  return tasks.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return  {
      ...acc,
      [curr.id] : {
        ...curr
      }
    }
  }, {})
}

export const initialState = {
  boardId: '',
  boardName: '',
  boardDescription: '',
  tasks: {},
  columns: {
    TO_DO: {
      status: 'TO_DO',
      title: 'To do',
      taskIds: []
    },
    IN_PROGRESS: {
      status: 'IN_PROGRESS',
      title: 'In progress',
      taskIds: []
    },
    DONE: {
      status: 'DONE',
      title: 'Done',
      taskIds: []
    }
  },
  columnOrder: ['TO_DO', 'IN_PROGRESS', 'DONE']
}


const taskSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'task',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addTask (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<TaskPayload>) {
      const { task } = payload
      return {
        ...state,
        tasks: {
          ...state.tasks,
          [task.id]: task
        },
        columns: {
          ...state.columns,
          [task.status]: {
            ...state.columns[task.status],
            taskIds: [
              ...state.columns[task.status].taskIds,
              task.id
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    deleteTask (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<DeleteTaskPayload>) {
      const { column, id } = payload
      const { [id]: deleted, ...restTasks }: Tasks = state.tasks
      return {
        ...state,
        tasks: {
          ...restTasks
        },
        columns: {
          ...state.columns,
          [column]: {
            ...state.columns[column],
            taskIds: [
              ...state.columns[column]?.taskIds?.filter((taskId:string) => taskId !== id)
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    editTask (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<EditTaskPayload>) {
      const { task } = payload
      return {
        ...state,
        tasks: {
          ...state.tasks,
          [task.id]: task
        },
        columns: {
          ...state.columns,
          [task.column]: {
            ...state.columns[task.column],
            taskIds: [
              ...state.columns[task.column].taskIds
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    replaceTask (state, {payload}: PayloadAction<TaskPayload>) {
      const { task } = payload
      return {
        ...state,
        tasks: {
          ...state.tasks,
          [task.id]: task
        }
      }
    },
    moveTask (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<MoveTaskPayload>) {
      const {
        taskId,
        sourceIndex,
        sourceColumn,
        destinationIndex,
        destinationColumn
      } = payload
      const sourceTaskIdsClone = [...state.columns[sourceColumn].taskIds] as string[]

      if (sourceColumn === destinationColumn) {
        sourceTaskIdsClone.splice(sourceIndex, 1)
        sourceTaskIdsClone.splice(destinationIndex, 0, taskId)
        return {
          ...state,
          columns: {
            ...state.columns,
            [sourceColumn]: {
              ...state.columns[sourceColumn],
              taskIds: sourceTaskIdsClone
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        sourceTaskIdsClone.splice(sourceIndex, 1)
        const destinationTaskIdsClone = [...state.columns[destinationColumn].taskIds] as string[]
        destinationTaskIdsClone.splice(destinationIndex, 0, taskId)
        return {
          ...state,
          tasks: {
            ...state.tasks,
            [taskId]: {
              ...state.tasks[taskId], // TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'WritableDraft<{}>'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'WritableDraft<{}>'.
              column: destinationColumn,
              status: initialState.columns[destinationColumn].status
            }
          },
          columns: {
            ...state.columns,
            [sourceColumn]: {
              ...state.columns[sourceColumn],
              taskIds: sourceTaskIdsClone
            },
            [destinationColumn]: {
              ...state.columns[destinationColumn],
              taskIds: destinationTaskIdsClone
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    hydrateTasks (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<HydrateTasksPayload>) { // Types of property 'boardDescription' are incompatible.Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      const {board, tasks} = payload
      const {TO_DO, IN_PROGRESS, DONE} = board
      if (typeof board.id !== 'undefined') {
        return {
          boardId: board.id,
          boardName: board.name,
          boardDescription: board.description,
          tasks: reduceTasks(tasks),
          columnOrder: ['TO_DO', 'IN_PROGRESS', 'DONE'],
          columns: {
            TO_DO: {
              status: 'TO_DO',
              title: 'To do',
              taskIds: [...TO_DO]
            },
            IN_PROGRESS: {
              status: 'IN_PROGRESS',
              title: 'In progress',
              taskIds: [...IN_PROGRESS]
            },
            DONE: {
              status: 'DONE',
              title: 'Done',
              taskIds: [...DONE]
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        return {
          boardId: board.id,
          boardName: board.name,
          tasks: reduceTasks(tasks),
          columnOrder: ['TO_DO', 'IN_PROGRESS', 'DONE'],
          columns: {
            TO_DO: {
              status: 'TO_DO',
              title: 'To do',
              taskIds: [...TO_DO]
            },
            IN_PROGRESS: {
              status: 'IN_PROGRESS',
              title: 'In progress',
              taskIds: [...IN_PROGRESS]
            },
            DONE: {
              status: 'DONE',
              title: 'Done',
              taskIds: [...DONE]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

export const { addTask, deleteTask, editTask, moveTask, addBoard, editBoard, hydrateTasks, replaceTask } = taskSlice.actions
export default taskSlice.reducer
```

The second error has been edited for concision as it is way too long. I have tried to get around the second error by only adding the `boardDescription` if `typeof board.description !== 'undefined'` I believe this is called a type guard? That did not change anything. I do not know what to try for the first error. I will continue studying TS online. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be most grateful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Indicate initialState type, `export const initialState: TaskSlice = { .... }`

Comment: @reduxjs/toolkit use immer,  replaceTask can write like `replaceTask(state, {payload: {task}}){ state.tasks[task.id] = task }` details: https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#application-usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three typing issues in your code.

First, on `hydrateTasks` you're getting a long compiler error that ends with

```
        Types of property 'boardDescription' are incompatible.
          Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

which refers to two places, namely this line:

```
boardDescription: board.description,
```

and the `else` block.

This is because `state.boardDescription` is a string, but on `HydrateTasksPayload`, `board.description` is optional, and in the `else` block you're not setting it at all.

So you either have to remove the question mark, i.e. making `board.description` required in the action, or provide a fallback for the case that the action doesn't specify a description, e.g. keeping it as is by taking it from the base state:

```
boardDescription: board.description ?? state.boardDescription,
```

(what you pick here depends on your desired semantics). This needs to happen in both `if` branches.

Second, in `EditTaskPayload` you have a task property called `boardId`, but it has to be `board` (matching `Task`).

Third, the remainder of your errors come from the fact that you don't explicitly provide the interface of your state object, and instead let the compiler infer it from your `initialState`.

That is not a problem per se, but you have to give the compiler a few more pieces of information.

It means you either have to define an `interface State { ... }` and say `const initialState: State = { ... }`, or you add this information directly in the definition of `initialState`.

```
tasks: {},
```

That ^ tells the compiler that `initialState.tasks` is an empty object. It doesn't know that you mean for it to be a map from IDs to `Task` objects, you have to tell it that:

```
tasks: {} as Tasks,
```

And your column objects (all three of them, I'm just using one as an example) have two of those problems.

```
    TO_DO: {
      status: 'TO_DO',
      title: 'To do',
      taskIds: []
    },
```

`taskIds` is an empty array -- the compiler doesn't know that it's meant to be a *string* array.

And `status: 'TO_DO'` makes the compiler widen `status` to a string, *any* string. But you mean for it to be *that one specific* string, always. There's a couple of different ways to express that; the simplest one is [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

```
    TO_DO: {
      status: 'TO_DO' as const,
      title: 'To do',
      taskIds: [] as string[]
    },
```

(You might run into a similar issue with `title`, because elsewhere you've also typed that as a union type, but currently your code doesn't violate the typings in that regard).

With those changes your code now compiles.

Comment: you should teach a course on TypeScript. You explain things very well.